# Jquery hover vs. click expandable menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

A client has a site built in Magento, and there's this bit of javascript controlling how the menu is displayed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery('.nav-add li.level0, .nav li').hover(
function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.nav-widget:not(.inSlide), ul:not(.inSlide)').addClass('inSlide').slideDown(700,function(){

    });
},
function(){
    jQuery(this).children('.nav-widget, ul:not(.active)').delay('2000').slideUp(500,function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass('inSlide');
    });
}
)
jQuery('.nav-widget').hide();

</script>
```

Right now it's set to expand whenever the user hovers on an item, but it's rather annoying to try to navigate that way. Is it possible to modify this code so that it expands when a user clicks on an item?

I tried replacing .hover with .click or .mouseup to no avail.

Comment: What behavior do you want on `click`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want to toggle the hover behavior by `click` instead of `hover` you can try something like this.

```
jQuery('.nav-add li.level0, .nav li').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).data('clicked')){
       jQuery(this)
       .data('clicked', true)
       .children('.nav-widget:not(.inSlide), ul:not(.inSlide)')
       .addClass('inSlide')
       .slideToggle(700,function(){

       });
    }
    else{
       jQuery(this)
       .data('clicked', false)
       .children('.nav-widget, ul:not(.active)')
       .delay('2000')
       .slideUp(500,function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass('inSlide');
       });
    }
});
jQuery('.nav-widget').hide();
```

Comment: That didn't quite work, but I think it's because the menus in Magento are dynamically generated based on your product categories and navigate to a product category page when you click a main menu item, rather than expand the submenu. To get this to work, I'll have to find a way to make the main category items unclickable. This is probably why I haven't seen anyone else with a true accordion/expandable style menu.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work by simply replacing the .hover() with .click() is because the hover event needs two functions, one for onhover one for offhover.  The .click() event only takes one function.  I assume you want the top function as your click event.

```
jQuery('.nav-add li.level0, .nav li').click(
    function(){
        jQuery(this).children('.nav-widget:not(.inSlide),
        ul:not(.inSlide)').addClass('inSlide').slideDown(700,function(){
    });
}
```