# jQuery prevent 2nd level links being followed

Tags: jquery, magento, jquery-ui-accordion

I followed this tutorial on making an expanding side navigation with jQuery in Magento:

http://benfrain.com/notepad/2011/05/magento-add-an-expanding-accordion-style-vertical-side-menu.html

I've got it working, but I'm trying to figure out how to make the 2nd level links be expandable like the 1st level.

This is the section in the jquery.menubf.js file that prevents the first level links from being followed:

```
jQuery('ul#vertnav > li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

jQuery('ul#vertnav > li, ul#vertnav > li > ul > li').click(function(){
    var selfClick = jQuery(this).find('ul:first').is(':visible');
    if(!selfClick) {
        jQuery(this)
        .parent()
        .find('> li ul:visible')
        .slideToggle();

    }

    jQuery(this)
        .find('ul:first')
        .stop(true, true)
        .slideToggle(); 
});
```

The author is no longer supporting this guide, and I'm pretty lost at how to modify this script. Any jQuery rockstars care to point me in the right direction?

EDIT: This is what the output looks like:

```
<div class="vertnav-container">
<div class="">
<h4 class="no-display">Category Navigation:</h4>
<ul id="vertnav">
<li class="first level0-active level0 active products open">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products.html"><span>Products</span></a></span>
<ul>
<li class="first level1-inactive level1 inactive sitetion">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/sitetion.html"><span>sitetion</span></a></span>

</li>
<li class="level1-inactive level1 inactive ultrasonics">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/ultrasonics.html"><span>Ultrasonics</span></a></span>

</li>
<li class="level1-inactive level1 inactive surgery">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/surgery.html"><span>Surgery</span></a></span>

</li>
<li class="level1-inactive level1 inactive irrigation">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/irrigation.html"><span>Irrigation</span></a></span>

</li>
<li class="last level1-inactive level1 inactive diagnostics">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/diagnostics.html"><span>Diagnostics</span></a></span>

</li>

</ul>
</li>
<li class="next level0-inactive level0 inactive contact-us">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/contact-us.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></span>

</li>
<li class="last level0-inactive level0 inactive about-us">
<span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/about-us.html"><span>About Us</span></a></span>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="left-widget student-widget">
<h1>
Are you a registered Endodontic resident? <a href="http://dev.site.com/customer/account/create/?student=1" title="Create an Student Account">Sign up</a> to receive our university pricing.
</h1>
</div>
</div> 

    <div class="col-main">

                                <div class="std"><div class="home-content" style="display: none;">

<ul class="home-featured">

<li> <a href="http://dev.site.com/products.html/"><img src="http://dev.site.com/skin/frontend/default/orbtura/images/home/list1.jpg" alt="E-store specials" /></a> <a class="button blue-button" href="http://dev.site.com/products.html/">E-store specials</a> </li>

<li> <a href="http://dev.site.com/products/featured-products.html/"><img src="http://dev.site.com/skin/frontend/default/orbtura/images/home/list2.jpg" alt="Featured products" /></a> <a class="button blue-button" href="http://dev.site.com/products/featured-products.html/">Featured products</a> </li>

<li> <a href="http://dev.site.com/endoeducation/videos.html/"><img src="http://dev.site.com/skin/frontend/default/orbtura/images/home/list3.jpg" alt="Featured video" /></a> <a class="button blue-button" href="http://dev.site.com/endoeducation/videos.html/">Featured video</a> </li>

</ul>

</div></div><div style="margin-top: 30px"class="category-grid">
<ul>

<li>
<a class="image" href="http://dev.site.com/products/sitetion.html">
    <img class="css3-border"  src="http://dev.site.com/media/catalog/category/cache/1/thumbnail/190x170/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/sitetion_button_1.jpg" alt="sitetion"/>
</a>
<a class="button" href="http://dev.site.com/products/sitetion.html">sitetion</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="image" href="http://dev.site.com/products/ultrasonics.html">
    <img class="css3-border"  src="http://dev.site.com/media/catalog/category/cache/1/thumbnail/190x170/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/ultrasonic_button_1.jpg" alt="Ultrasonics"/>
</a>
<a class="button" href="http://dev.site.com/products/ultrasonics.html">Ultrasonics</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="image" href="http://dev.site.com/products/surgery.html">
    <img class="css3-border"  src="http://dev.site.com/media/catalog/category/cache/1/thumbnail/190x170/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/microsurgery_button_1.jpg" alt="Surgery"/>
</a>
<a class="button" href="http://dev.site.com/products/surgery.html">Surgery</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="image" href="http://dev.site.com/products/irrigation.html">
    <img class="css3-border"  src="http://dev.site.com/media/catalog/category/cache/1/thumbnail/190x170/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/Irrigation_button.jpg" alt="Irrigation"/>
</a>
<a class="button" href="http://dev.site.com/products/irrigation.html">Irrigation</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="image" href="http://dev.site.com/products/diagnostics.html">
    <img class="css3-border"  src="http://dev.site.com/media/catalog/category/cache/1/thumbnail/190x170/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/diagnostics_button_3.jpg" alt="Diagnostics"/>
</a>
<a class="button" href="http://dev.site.com/products/diagnostics.html">Diagnostics</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

jQuery(window).load(function(){
AutoHeigthLine(3,".category-grid li");
AutoHeigthLine(3,".category-grid a.button");
});

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What does your HTML structure look like?

Comment: The HTML for the menu is dynamically generated based on the categories and products

Comment: Can you grab the output from from your developer tools? Let the page load, then inspect the `#vertnav` element in your dev. tools and copy the HTML structure of the element. It's very difficult (impossible?) to debug your selectors without knowing the HTML structure that the selectors are trying to traverse.

Comment: I added the output above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did was change the first `click` event handler to stop the propagation of `click` events, so the `<li>` element that is actually clicked will be the only one to receive the `click` event and I added a nested `<ul>` element as a third tier.

JS --

```
jQuery('#vertnav li').click(function() {
    return false;
});

jQuery('#vertnav > li, #vertnav > li > ul > li').click(function(){
    if(!jQuery(this).find('ul').eq(0).is(':visible')) {
        jQuery(this)
        .siblings().find('ul:visible')
        .slideToggle();

    }

    jQuery(this)
        .find('ul').eq(0)
        .stop(true, true)
        .slideToggle(); 
});
```

Notice I removed the `tagName`s from selectors wherever possible and instead of using the `:first` pseudo-selector I used `.eq(0)` to get the first result. I also changed the `.parent().find('> li')` selector to `.siblings()` since selecting a parent then child is the same as selecting a sibling. These will all make the code perform faster.

HTML --

```
<ul id="vertnav">
    <li class="first level0-active level0 active products open">
        <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products.html"><span>Products</span></a></span>
        <ul>
            <li class="first level1-inactive level1 inactive sitetion">
                <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/sitetion.html"><span>sitetion</span></a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Third Tier</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="level1-inactive level1 inactive ultrasonics">
                <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/ultrasonics.html"><span>Ultrasonics</span></a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="level1-inactive level1 inactive surgery">
                <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/surgery.html"><span>Surgery</span></a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="level1-inactive level1 inactive irrigation">
                <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/irrigation.html"><span>Irrigation</span></a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="last level1-inactive level1 inactive diagnostics">
                <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/products/diagnostics.html"><span>Diagnostics</span></a></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="next level0-inactive level0 inactive contact-us">
        <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/contact-us.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a></span>
    </li>
    <li class="last level0-inactive level0 inactive about-us">
        <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="http://dev.site.com/about-us.html"><span>About Us</span></a></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8EvRB/2/

Comment: Hmmm. I replaced the jQuery with your revised version, but still not seeing the third level. This is the dev site if you care to take a look: dev.obtura.com

Comment: I looked at the source for the page and you aren't coding in an third tier, you have to add a `<ul>` element to a second tier `<li>` element... Look at my jsfiddle for an example on this. The JS code you posted works fine, but your HTML structure needs to be updated to reflect what you want to happen.

Comment: I'm not sure how to code in a third level because the menu is generated, but I know there is a third level that should appear. Check the site again, I put the old nav back up (which is what I've been trying to replace with the click-expandable style menu), which uses a hover to expose the levels. At first I just tried modifying the old menu to click-expand how I want it to, but that didn't seem to work. I posted that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104024/jquery-hover-vs-click-expandable-menu

Comment: The two menus have different HTML. I looked again and there aren't any third tier `<ul>` elements in your new menu. You have to add them...